# How to add implicit imports to ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

I am using a the `PYTHONSTARTUP=~/pythonstartup.py` approach in order to make ipython the default python shell but I want to extend it do have some additional imports by default (like importing few common packages).

How can I do that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import re
import time
import platform
import IPython

os.environ['PYTHONSTARTUP'] = ''  # Prevent running this again
IPython.start_ipython()
raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by adding

```
IPython.start_ipython(user_ns=locals())
```